# Group by one column and sum another column in a Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, sum, grouping

I'm faily new to PHP & Laravel, and i've been given this task:
I have a collection that looks like the one below:

```
   Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [cardId] => 100
                    [cardQuantity] => 1234      
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [cardId] => 100
                    [cardQuantity] => 1234            
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [cardId] => 200
                    [cardQuantity] => 1234   
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                    [id] => 8
                    [cardId] => 200
                    [cardQuantity] => 1234   
                )   
        )

)
```

and i have to filter each element based on the `cardId` parameter, add (+) the `cardQuantity` parameter, and then return new, distinct arrays that look like this:

```
  (
     [id] => 10
     [cardId] => 100
     [cardQuantity] => 2468      
  )
  (
     [id] => 11
     [cardId] => 200
     [cardQuantity] => 2468      
  )
```

How does one can achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a vision about how to achieve this trying something like this:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'cardId' => 100, 'cardQuantity' => 1234],
    ['id' => 2, 'cardId' => 100, 'cardQuantity' => 1234],
    ['id' => 7, 'cardId' => 200, 'cardQuantity' => 1234],
    ['id' => 8, 'cardId' => 200, 'cardQuantity' => 1234],
]);

$unique = $collection->unique('cardId'); // returns a collection

$unique->transform(function ($item, $key) use ($collection) {
    $id = $item['cardId'];

    $item['cardQuantity'] = $collection->sum(function ($product) use ($id) {
        if($product['cardId'] == $id){
            return $product['cardQuantity'];
        }
    });
    return $item;
});
return $unique->all();
```

The result this code returns is the unique collection transformed:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "cardId": 100,
        "cardQuantity": 2468
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 7,
        "cardId": 200,
        "cardQuantity": 2468
    }
}
```

Basically, first we get the unique values by the `cardId` key, after that we'll [`transform`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-transform) the `unique` collection, setting it's new values (the sum of the uniques). You can play and test more ways to do it. Hope you can find this useful.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction! I'll play around with your answer and i'll read up more on Laravel's collection methods.